# Error in Synapse dataflow while connecting to SAP SLT via SAP CDC Connector

Tags: azure-synapse, azure-data-lake-gen2, sap-erp

I have the following Setup:

SAP ECC -> SAP LT (SLT) -> SAP CDC Connector (ODP) -> Azure Synapse/Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 (parquet)

The connection via the SAP CDC connector is working, I see all available tables and when I choose one table, the meta data can be loaded to Azure (data preview is not supported with SLT).

On SLT side the request looks also good - no errors. It starts the initial load and shows also the number of records.

But I am getting the error message below after a couple of minutes when I debug the dataflow in Azure Synapse to load the data:

> Operation on target TARGETNAME failed: {"StatusCode":"DF-SAPODP-ExecuteFuncModuleWithPointerFailed","Message":"Job failed due to reason: at Source 'KNA1': Error Message: DF-SAPODP-012 - SapOdp copy activity failure with run id: c194054d-876f-4684-8105-9e038ca3b7e1, error code: 2200 and error message: Failure happened on 'Source' side. ErrorCode=SapOdpOperationFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Sap Odp operation 'Execute function module RODPS_REPL_ODP_FETCH with pointer 20221107095340.000094000, package id 20221107095436.000183000' failed. Error Number: '404', error message: 'DataSource QUEUENAME~KNA1 does not exist in version A',Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Runtime.SapRfcHelper,'","Details":""}

Does anyone knows what the error message means? The table KNA1 is available, the User has all necessary permissions, connection works.

Thanks,
Frank

What I have done so far on Azure site:

- used another table
- checked prerequesites
- checked user permission
- changed target from parquet to csv in Dataflow sink

What I have done so far on SAP site:

- checked RODPS_REPL_ODP_FETCH
- checked SLT monitoring
- checked ODQMON

Answer (score 0):

​Hi all,

SAP provided a fix to this issue and I was now able to solve it. The main issue is an outdated version of the SLT, so with a new Version this issue should not appear. If an upgrade of the version is not possible due to dependencies to other systems the following notes needs to be implemented in SAP (SLT).

2232584 - Release of SAP extractors for ODP replication (ODP SAPI)

2459760 - DataSource  does not exist in Version A - Data Services (implement SAP Notes 2324659 and 2427380)

The Notes 2324659 and 2427380 solved this problem.
Regards,
Frank